# How to set label according to text but i want background color also

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uilabel

How to set **`UILabel`** according to **text** but I want **`backGroundColor`** also in it, if **text** is small then it will display **background small label with background color black** and text and vice-versa.How to do?

[image]

In image the black background color came according to the  dynamic text. I want black background color till the text India.

Comment: please elaborate amit...

Answer (score 2):

for UILabel to fit all text use sizeToFit

```
[label sizeToFit];
```

If you want to have pic background make its size as the label size, take an imageview

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);
```

or if want only background color of the label then use

```
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
NSString *sample = @"...";
CGSize txtSz = [sample sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica" size: 16]];
CGRect lblFrame = CGRectMake(10,50, txtSz.width, txtSz.height);
yourLabel.frame = lblFrame;
yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the width of the text and assign it to Label frame width.

Answer (score 1):

this is am done in my app you must like did this

```
    label.text = @"Some text" ;

                        CGSize textSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font];

                        backView.frame=CGRectMake(startPointX, startPointY, textSize.width, 1);
```

here you must create a new view on back of the label and that name is backview and set the frame of that view and then show it it work perfectly in my app :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following code may be help you

```
        UILabel *biotitlelb = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,16)];
        [biotitlelb setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [biotitlelb setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        biotitlelb.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        biotitlelb.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12]; 
        biotitlelb.text = @"sometext";
        CGSize textSize = [biotitlelb.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12]];
        CGFloat strikeWidth = textSize.width;
        [biotitlelb setframe:CGRectMake(0,0,strikeWidth,16)];
```