# Scale a multi line label in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have a UITableView with multiple height for each cell:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        return 100;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row==7){

        return 200;
    }
    else {
        return 40;
    }

}
```

The problem is in the 7th row with height 200, I have this:
[image]

It's just showing the end of the label.
I modified the number of lines of that label to "0" in IB.

What could be the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the label's dimensions. Enlarge the label's size to occupy all the space available in the cell.

If you're using Xib for creating this cell. Attach struts to bottom of the view and let spring's enlarge it. If you're doing it programmatically, enlarge the frame like this:

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(50, 10, 320, 150); // replace these with appropriate values.
```

Comment: What about getting the label frame and setting the cell with that frame.height ?

Comment: That's a very good way to doing it. The whole point here is that label's height is not sufficient. So you'll need to determine the sufficient height for label to accommodate the text (all possible variations of it) and change lebel height to that

Answer (score 0):

give

```
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```

Also this [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174007/how-to-calculate-uilabel-height-dynamically) is very helpful for you.