# Monotouch - calculate UILabel height

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to create a custom cell which consists a few UILabels.
The first label might take one or more rows, so I need to resize the label according to the number of lines (after setting the number of lines to 0, so multi-line will be enabled).

I have tried setting sizeToFit(), but it changed the alignment and width of my label.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174007/how-to-calculate-uilabel-height-dynamically)

but I don't know how to convert it to C#.

Can anyone point me to an example? (I already tried Googling it off-course)

This is the method from the link:

```
// UILabel *myLabel;

CGSize labelSize = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont:myLabel.font 
                        constrainedToSize:myLabel.frame.size 
                            lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGFloat labelHeight = labelSize.height;


int lines = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont:myLabel.font 
                 constrainedToSize:myLabel.frame.size 
                     lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height/16; 
         // '16' is font size
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var size = myLabel.StringSize("Some really long string", myLabel.Font, myLabel.Frame.Size, UILineBreakMode.CharacterWrap);
var lines = size.Height / myLabel.Font.CapHeight;
```

Comment: When tried I get an error saying StringSize doesn't take 7 parameters. 
Checked in the assembly for the declaration:
 
.
public static CGSize StringSize (this NSString This, UIFont font, nfloat minFontSize, ref nfloat actualFontSize, nfloat forWidth, UILineBreakMode lineBreakMode);

But it also mentioned its deprecated in ios 7.0

Any alternate solutions is much appreciated! Thanks.